# Change height of a NSProgressIndicator programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I cannot find a way to set the height of a `NSProgressIndicator` programmatically.

My try so far:

```c
NSProgressIndicator *ind = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] init];
[ind setStyle: NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle];
// Height does not change height of the actual indicator
[ind setFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[ind setBounds: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 50)];
//[ind setControlSize: 0]; does only make it smaller, not bigger
[view addSubview: ind];
```

I found `NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle` enumeration in the documentation, but I couldn't find a method to specify the thickness.

Here a screenshot describing my problem: (layer has a background of red for better understanding):

[image]

This also occurs when using the `NSButton` class. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You can't properly do this. Many widgets in Cocoa use bitmaps to draw. The bitmaps are of fixed size. They wouldn't work right if scaled arbitrarily. If you set the `bounds` **not** to match the frame but to match the normal height, you might get the graphics to stretch, but it would look awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS You can't change the progress indicator height just changing its frame, due to framework restrictions. However you should be able to achieve the same result, playing with transform

```
_indicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 0.6f);
```

EDIT: I just tried on Mac OS X

```
_indicator.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f);
```

and it doesn't work, so it is not like iOS, likely because of how it is implemented on Cocoa (like Ken suggested).
The only way I managed to change the height is using `controlSize`, but I don't think it will suit your needs (since it doesn't allow you to specify points).

```
[_indicator setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize]; // or NSSmallControlSize
```

You should be able to use an arbitrary frame by subclassing `NSProgressIndicator`, and overriding `drawRect`, at this point my recommendation would be to look around to find something that can be extended for your use, like this one
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lbprogressbar

Comment: Sadly, there is no property called `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

in IB you can

1. select your NSProgressIndicator control
2. in the utilities view select the View Effects inspector
3. press + in Content Filters
4. select Lanczos Scale Transform filter
5. set the appropriate scale value in the Scale row
6. set the Aspect Ratio too if you need to change the height only

this can be added programmatically also, just google for it how to add Content Filters to NSView

Comment: Scaling a layer makes your graphics uncrispy. One should subclass `NSView` achieve that kind of task, although its not trivial.

Comment: and that is why you down voted? distortion of the graphics are depending on several factors, i've done this trick several times, in most of the cases with acceptable or perfect result, if you do not like the result choose another more complex method, this is just one, in most cases acceptable, simple solution